# StackOverflow - you just overflowed with the ads !

Tags: discussion, advertising

StackOverflow's team hello,

Viewed a question and just noticed, for the first time, that there's a huge advertisement above the original question (for ServerFault).

Revenue is great BUT that's the point where your stack (of ads) got overflowed (: 
Don't ruin a great place!

I'm sure some people here agree with me.

Answer (score 11):

Get 200 reputation and it'll go away. This has been the case for months.

Answer (score 7):

That's one of the bigger clues to me when I stumble across a SO site while not logged in. The big ad banner.

Comment: -1 should've been a comment

Comment: +1 to undo the "-1" trigger happy users.

Comment: @Chris S: flagged as offensive because I find offensive that you feel the need to upvote a post that you might have ignored just because someone else decided to downvote him, and not because of its content.